# Receiving a syntax-error while trying to get the output of an external exe-file

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, syntax-error

**I'm trying to get the output of an exe in python (called: *ibstat.exe*).**

As this exe is on an external server, I got one possible output and used it to make a mock-object. (As I don't know how to create exe-files I made a ibstat.py mock-object.)

When I was done writing and testing my programm locally on my computer, I went back to the external server to test it again there. But I got this Error message:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x90' in file hello.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details"
```

I used this to get the output of the exe-file:
`subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, "ibstat.exe", "34"])`

when this didn't work I also tried:
`subprocess.call([sys.executable, "ibstat.exe"])`
`subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "ibstat.exe"])`

On my computer when I was opening *ibstat.py* everything was working just fine (with *call*, *Popen* and *check_output*).
And executing *ibstat.exe* on the server in the command-shell works too.

**Questions:**

1. Is there anything I overlooked/I forgot to do/try?
2. What can I do to open the exe properly without getting the
   Syntaxerror?
3. Do I need to clarify my question more clearly, or is more
   Information needed?

---

---

**Removing `sys.executable` SOLVED the issue.**

Comment: You do not need `sys.executable` to run an compiled executable.  `sys.executable` expects *Python code*, not compiled code.  So leave that out of your args list.  You may also need to provide the full path to `"ibstat.exe"`.

Comment: I removed sys.executable and now it works. Thank you very much!! I've been searching for a solution for hours!